# DJANGO regular expression not match specific file extensions

Tags: regex, django

trying to build on below statement and want to give exception for csv, xlsx, txt file extensions.

```
(r'', 'myproject.myapp.views.list'),
```

above is a redirection to list.html or home page
how to add exception in above statement so that it do redirect to list.html from any url request but do not redirect if the request is for csv, xlsx, txt file (then it should react normaly)

tried below combinations, none of these works.

(r'.+\^csv|xlsx', 'myproject.myapp.views.list'),

....

(r'(^csv|xlsx)', 'myproject.myapp.views.list'),

....

(r'^('^'xlsx)\', 'myproject.myapp.views.list'),

very new to reg ex world, please help

Comment: Why not learning regular expression instead of trying just anything hope it will magically "work" ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match anything that ends with csv or xlsx:

```
(r'^.*csv|xlsx$', 'myproject.myapp.views.list')
```

Comment: how i can adjust this in (r'', 'myproject.myapp.views.list'), i am trying to add exception for CSV and other format with **r ' '**